# How to configure auto import in PhpStorm for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I want to forbid PhpStorm to create imports like below:

```
import {SomeClass} from "path";
import AnotherClass = SomeClass.AnotherClass;

let some: AnotherClass;
```

Instead I want auto-import to do this:

```
import {SomeClass} from "path";

let some: SomeClass.AnotherClass;
```

Is it possible to configure?

Comment: would you expect the auto-import to change a short type name to a FQ name instead of generating the import? No, this can't be done, this is not the thing the auto-import is supposed to do

Comment: I may be mistaken, but in other languages (C# for example), IDE doesn't create shortcuts and just paste `SomeClass.AnotherClass` instead of `AnotherClass` in similar cases. And in TS both cases are valid, so why not to make it configurable?